# Scope for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have several objects that all have an `approved` field.

What would be the best way to implement a scope to use across all models?

For example, I have a `sighting` object and a `comment` object. They both have to be approved by an admin before being availalbe to the public.

So how can I create a scope that returns `comment.approved` as well as `sighting.approved` respectively without repeating it on each model?  Is this where concerns comes into play?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

While just declaring a scope in each model is fine if you just want the scoping functionality. Using an `ActiveSupport::Concern` will give you the ability to add additional methods as well if that's something you think is going to happen. Here's an example:

```
# /app/models/concerns/approved.rb
module Approved
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    default_scope { where(approved: false) }
    scope :approved, -> { where(approved: true) }
  end

  def unapprove
    update_attribute :approved, false
  end
end

class Sighting < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Approved
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Approved
end
```

Then you can make calls like `Sighting.approved` and `Comment.approved` to get the appropriate list of approved records. You also get the `unapprove` method and can do something like `Comment.approved.first.unapprove`.

In this example, I've also included `default_scope` which will mean that calls like `Sighting.all` or `Comment.all` will return only unapproved items. I included this just as an example, it may not be applicable to your implementation.

Comment: Note, you may need to add `config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/app/models/concerns"` to your application.rb to autoload the concerns. Rails 4 will load them by default though.

Comment: One problem I found is having Devise's current_user picking up the concerns consistently. It seems like there's a disconnect between the set_current_user method, self.current thread in User.rb and the approved concern. When I log in and out it doesn't always recapture the updated approved scope.

Comment: Code example: `included do
    if User.current && !User.current.nil?
      scope :approved, -> { where("#{self.table_name}.status_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)") }
    else
      scope :approved, -> { where("#{self.table_name}.status_id IN (1)") }
    end
  end`

Comment: Found the answer here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28284597/rails-concerns-scopes-devise-user-current-and-current-user/28284899#28284899

Comment: using `default_scope` without curly braces is deprecated. That should be written as `default_scope {where(:approved => false)}`

Comment: @JackCollins Thanks! Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although I've noticed the scope pulled from the concerns needs to be the last scope when concatenating scopes. I'm not quite sure why.

```
Comment.existing.approved
```

When I tried it as:

```
Comment.approved.existing
```

It failed silently.

And I take that back. I was migrating older code and using scopes with conditions instead of lambdas. When I replaced :conditions the scope order no longer mattered.

```
scope :existing, -> { where("real = 1") }
```

replaced

```
scope :existing, :conditions => "real = 1"
```