# Rails: Get outer class name inside concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I get the class name of a model I am including a concern into?

I am creating a concern for a scope as described in here https://stackoverflow.com/a/14483808/1715035 but need the model name for polymorphic search.

`self.table_name` works fine and so does `self.table_name.singularize.titleize.gsub(/\s+/, "")` but maybe theres an easier way to get the class name.

Comment: Remember `self` _IS_ the class itself :) Like Andy says; just use `self` , `self.name`, or just `name`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use the `name` method as you would in the class itself.

```
module M
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :my_fancy_scope, where(some_type: name)
  end
end
```

Comment: Ah, for some reason i kept trying self.class.name, but yeah this works great!

Comment: The `included` block is executed in the class's context, where `self` would be `YourModel` and therefore `self.class` would be `Class` - not what you want! :)

Comment: Actually `self.class.name` would result in what you want as well. Although I couldn't find the fact that `self = TheClass`, in the documentation.

Comment: @vint-i-vuit I don't think that's true; as I said in my comment, `self` is the class object `YourModel`, so `self.name` is `"YourModel"`. However, because `YourModel` is a class object, `self.class` is `Class`, and `self.class.name` is `"Class"`.

Comment: @AndyH: You are right! I missed the fact that I am calling `self.name.class` outside of the `included do... end` block. In particular in my `included` block I've got a callback `before_create :generate_token`, and I define `def generate_token;...end` outside the `included` block, where `self` is pointing to the *instance*, not the *class object*.