# Rails Concerns, Scopes, Devise, User.current and current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using a concern for showing records based on status. If you are logged in you can see unapproved records and the public can only view approved records.

```
module Approved
 extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
   if User.current && !User.current.nil?
    scope :approved, -> { where("#{self.table_name}.status_id IN (1,2,3)") }
   else
    scope :approved, -> { where("#{self.table_name}.status_id IN (1)") }
  end
end
end
```

I'm using Thread to set current user.

```
def self.current=(user)
  Thread.current[:current_user] = user
end

def self.current
  Thread.current[:current_user]
end
```

And in the application_controller i have a before_action calling set_current_user.

```
def set_current_user
  User.current = current_user
end
```

When I log out the unapproved records still pull from the query. It seems to skip over the concern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`included` fires at the moment of inclusion.

lambdas, however, fire each time.

Try this:

```
included do
  scope :approved, -> {
    ids = User.current.present? ? "(1,2,3)" : "(1)"
    where("#{self.table_name}.status_id IN #{ids}")
  }
end
```

Comment: Lovely solution. Thanks!